# C - Unable to get shmget/shmat to compile

Tags: c, shared-memory, minix

I'm pulling out my hair trying to figure out why this isn't working on my Minix system.

When I try to compile my C program, I get the following error:

```
#make
       link  pm/pm
program.o: In function `do_function':
program.c:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `shmget'
program.c:(.text+0x36): undefined reference to `shmat'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make: stopped in /usr/src/servers/pm
#
```

This is my code:

```
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
/* Some other includes here */

typedef struct {
    //struct elemLi *next;
    //elem sem;
    int ref_count;
} elemLi;

int do_function(void){
    int segment_id; //Shared Memory ID
    struct elemLi* sli; //Shared Memory Pointer
    segment_id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(elemLi),0660 | IPC_CREAT);
    sli = (struct elemLi *)shmat(segment_id,NULL,0);
    return -1;
}
```

As you can see, I've included the proper header files for these calls and it's still saying the references are undefined. I was able to successfully use this in another program, so I've completely run out of ideas as to why this isn't working in this instance.

Edit: This is within a system call. I assume that doesn't make a difference.

Comment: try include -lpthread when compiling

Comment: I may be doing it incorrectly (as I don't know where to actually put that), but I don't think that works. When I do "clang program.c -lpthread", it says "cannot find -lpthread"; when I do "clang program.c -c", it compiles without error, but if I try to manually do "ld program.o" (with or without -lpthread) I get errors like the ones above. And just to note, the above errors were from compiling through the Makefile already present in this system directory using just "make".

Comment: The error is not actually a compilation error––it is a link error.  This looks okay except that a library which satisfies the calls is not being linked in.  Are you sure that there should be one on Minix?

Comment: What exactly is being executed when the `link pm/pm` command is executed. That sort of abbreviated information is fine when all goes right; it is worse than useless when there's a problem. You might be able to see what's happening with `make -n`; you might have to more serious surgery on the `makefile`. But, without knowing what it's doing, we can't diagnose what the problem is and how to resolve it. (Is there a chance that a shared object is being built without linking with the C library, for example?)

Comment: This is the output from `make -n`:

`echo '   ' "   link " pm/pm [Line break]
clang      -static  -o pm  main.o forkexit.o break.o exec.o time.o alarm.o signal.o utility.o table.o getset.o misc.o profile.o schedule.o program.o mcontext.o trace.o -lsys -ltimers -nodefaultlibs -L/usr/pkg/compiler-rt/lib -lCompilerRT-Generic -lsys -lCompilerRT-Generic -lminc -lminlib -lcompat_minix`

Comment: Do the same 'make -n' on the program that works. You may find that the libraries used are different which could cause the linker to vomit.

Comment: The program that works is just a standalone program that compiles and runs fine with just `clang otherprogram.c -o otherprogram`, so there's no Makefile or linking.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone, it looks like it *was* a missing library in the linker. I added libc, using `-lc`, to the Makefile, and now it seems to be compiling fine.